# Jasper Report Books

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to do a Jasper Report Book, to fill its content later, and leaving the cover static, but when I use the .jasper corresponding to the Report Book, I get a blank page. I pass one at one the pages of the book, and it works, but when I pass the entire book, I get nothing.

anyone know how to work in java with a entire Jasper report book to generate a PDF?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. use select 1 as Query.
2. There is option to select in Report Page Properties ** When No Data** select All Section no Details .

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a datasource and do a query in the book report, to get at least one element